# Swift Framework has no generated header file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, frameworks

I have created Framework in Xcode(8.2.1) Every settings are done (I already have found many answers in StackOverFlow)

Define modules is OK, Objective-C Generated Interface Header Name is OK

Then, After Build framework, {PROJECT_NAME}-Swift.h has no public method.. So In other project can import this framework, However, I can't use any public method.

Comment: Not much to go on here. I use a Framework target (Swift 3 nowadays) all the time without an issue. You say you've found many answers here but not which ones you've tried. More to my point, **why** would you think the framework .h file should have any public methods? Mine doesn't. Oh, and beyond the Xcode version, could you give us the Swift version too, along with the project language (and version) you are trying to use this framework in? Thanks!

Comment: @dfd sorry for not clearly question. I'm using swift 3.0.2 version. and many tutorials and open sources projects shows has interfaces in .h file. but, I agree with you It doesn't need public methods in .h file.

Comment: I have solved this problem. I have checked my target scheme to shared. however, unchecked and built it, can see opened methods finally. (imported framework and you can see what methods opened by commnad+click) thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a public method in your .h file. Only change your classes and methods (The ones you want to be accessed within your app) to public.

What I use to do is to create a swift file called {PROJECT_NAME}.swift and use a singleton to manage all actions.

But, answering your question, your .h header file is not supposed to have public methods